# C# app needs both SQL db and oracle db connection in one app.config file

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, entity-framework, app-config

My C# app already connects to a SQL db and have the below provider in app.config file

```
provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"   
type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"
```

The connection works fine with this.

But the minute I add Oracle db provider

```
provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"
```

It is unable to connect to the SQL database, I'm getting error

> 'Initial Catalog' is an invalid connection string attribute

The dbconnection error says

> Connection = '((System.Data.Entity.DbContext)_dbContext).Database.Connection' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'.

Can I not include both providers in the same `app.config` file?

Comment: Sure you can - but you also need to have the **correct connection string** for each provider! You cannot use the SQL Server connection string for your Oracle DB ......

Answer (score 2):

You need two connection strings for each database & context and then you can register both of them separately in `program.cs`